# cell backgroung color remain after deselecting it.

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have one tableView. On selecting any row I am pushing another viewcontroller. I am changing color of selected cell. But now when I returns from other viewcontroller and select another row then previous selected cell color remaining same. I have done following to change it but it is not working.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

And this is how I am applying background color to cell:

```
-(UIView *)selectedCellView{
    UIView *cellView=[[UIView alloc]init];
    //cellView.backgroundColor=RGB(155,130,110);
    cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return cellView;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
cell.selectedBackgroundView=[self selectedCellView];
...
}
```

Comment: it would be much better if you can store the value of indexPath.row in a property and according to that property change the background color of cell and let the other cells background remain white or whatever color you like

Comment: Isn't the established pattern to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` etc?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes same I have used

Comment: @vivek Not really.  If the background color is set in `selectedCellView` and you **don't call** it (because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns non-`nil`) then that would explain your problem.  If you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` then move it into `selectedCellView`.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called every time the user scroll the tableView , that means you are allocating a UIView instance for every scroll. This adds a view above the defaultSelectionView. A simpler way is to change the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and change it back to the previous value in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` this method get called whenever cell is created so depending on number of cell ,it will be called. So you could simply change the in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and change back to original color in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method. Also you could use highlight option for showing selected cell with `cell.selectionStyle`. Also one thing that don't need to to call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method simple in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` u could change color and push or present your second view controller ,and just before pushing or presenting just change color of cell back to original color.